# Executing MongoDB Stored JavaScript/Procedures from Spring Java

Tags: mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I have few stored Javascripts in mongodb. I am using spring springframework.data.mongodb  to access mongodb. How can i execute stored JavaScripts/procedures from this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

found the solution.

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.append( "$eval" , "stored_javascript_name()" );

CommandResult t=mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj);
Object obj1=t.get("retval");
```

Comment: If the store procedure has parameters?

Comment: I found that if we wanna add parameter, we can do like this:

    
     `int id = 12;`
     `BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();`
     `obj.append( "$eval" , "stored_javascript_name("+ id  +")" );`
     `CommandResult t=mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj);`
     `Object obj1=t.get("retval");`

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
String menu="湖南卫视";
String program="天路啦：东方不亮西方亮";
obj.append( "$eval" , "keyword_store('"+menu+"','"+program+"')" );
```

Another thing you should know is adding single quotes when you transfer string parameter.